# Exceptions not flowing through HockeyApp bridge to Application Insights

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-application-insights, hockeyapp

We are trying to find a centralized exception logging solution for our line-of-business UWP app. After some research, we have decided to try HockeyApp, since it has a UWP SDK and a `TrackException()` method. We were hoping to view data in Azure by setting up a HockeyApp Bridge to Application Insights. However, while events are flowing through just fine, exceptions are not appearing in Application Insights. Below is simple code I've written to test. The `TrackEvent()` logs show up both in HockeyApp and App Insights. The `TrackException()` log shows up *only* in HockeyApp. Why are exceptions not flowing through to Application Insights?

```
HockeyClient.Current.TrackEvent($"Navigated to Login Page.");
HockeyClient.Current.TrackEvent($"Navigated to Login with Dictionary.", new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"MyExtraData", "Tour # 1234" }
    }
);
try
{
    string str = null;
    int i = str.Length;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HockeyClient.Current.TrackException(ex);
}
HockeyClient.Current.Flush();
```

Here's the exception in the HockeyApp portal. 
[image]

And here you can see there are no exceptions in Azure Application Insights.
[image]

I have reproduced this multiple times. Also, there is no "exceptions" table in the Analytics portal.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that HockeyApp is depricated and you are [suggested to move to AppCenter](https://hockeyapp.net/appcenter/transition/) or/and other complementary platform ASAP.

HockeyApp is not exporting exceptions to ApplicationInsights. If you want to query exceptions using Azure Log Analytics (Kusto) Queries you need to export it to manually export it.

AppCenter does not support exporting handled exceptions for further processing. It is not in [product roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/roadmap) but you may request this feature.

---

If you want to query your exceptions using ApplicationInsights you have to export those manually. You may use official [ApplicationInsights SDKs](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home) for exporting, just remember to re-use your InstrumentationKey if you want to share same ApplicationInsights instance with *HockeyApp/AppCenter's export*.